# How to train a custom sentence completion model using tensorflow?

Tags: nlp, tensorflow, generative-models, text-generation

###### What I have

A small corpus of English sentences (about 60,000).

###### The Task

Sentence completion model. Basically, something like
Input: "Paris is the"
Output: "Paris is the capital of France and a popular tourist destination."

###### Requirement

- Based on open source, obviously, without calling any ChatGPT API or such.
- Must use generative AI capability
- There must be a custom training/fine-tuning component, based on my corpus, i.e. not pre-built model for direct inference.
- Best if based on tensorflow, otherwise, maybe pytorch or huggingface.

###### My question

I know it is a big task, but wondering is there any accessible tutorial, documentations on this? I can see many tutorials on neural machine translations, CLIP etc. but not on sentence completion.

Comment: If you can use a GPU, see, for example, answers to [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/120532/how-to-prepare-my-dataset-for-t5/120892#120892).